# Adding custom Theme not working in Material UI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I made a custom theme following the docs line by line but there are no changes in my UI

The primary and secondary colours are the same as default and don't know how my other colours(warning, info, error) are not working from the start(before adding these custom colours).

for eg: In my `<Button>` tag, if I add `color="info"`, it gives the default white colour

***Note**: I haven't used `create-react-app` so my file structure is a bit different`*

**Screenshots & Repository link in the end*

Here are my files:

1. My theme file

```js
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import {
    blue,
    lightBlue,
    lightGreen,
    red,
    teal,
    yellow,
} from "@mui/material/colors";

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: blue["A400"],
        },
        secondary: {
            main: teal[400],
        },
        error: {
            main: red[500],
        },
        warning: {
            main: yellow["A200"],
        },
        info: {
            main: lightBlue[200],
        },
        success: {
            main: lightGreen[600],
        },
    },
});

export default theme;
```

2. In my App component, there is `Router` component which is wrapped by ThemeProvider

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Router from "./Router";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import theme from "../theme/Pallette";

function App() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Router />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default App;

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");

render(<App />, appDiv);
```

I tried logging my theme object and it gave the correct output

```js
{
  "breakpoints": {
    "keys": [
      "xs",
      "sm",
      "md",
      "lg",
      "xl"
    ],
    "values": {
      "xs": 0,
      "sm": 600,
      "md": 900,
      "lg": 1200,
      "xl": 1536
    },
    "unit": "px"
  },
  "direction": "ltr",
  "components": {},
  "palette": {
    "mode": "light",
    "primary": {
      "main": "#2979ff",
      "light": "rgb(83, 147, 255)",
      "dark": "rgb(28, 84, 178)",
      "contrastText": "#fff"
    },
    "secondary": {
      "main": "#26a69a",
      "light": "rgb(81, 183, 174)",
      "dark": "rgb(26, 116, 107)",
      "contrastText": "#fff"
    },
    "error": {
      "main": "#f44336",
      "light": "rgb(246, 104, 94)",
      "dark": "rgb(170, 46, 37)",
      "contrastText": "#fff"
    },
    "warning": {
      "main": "#ffff00",
      "light": "rgb(255, 255, 51)",
      "dark": "rgb(178, 178, 0)",
      "contrastText": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)"
    },
    "info": {
      "main": "#81d4fa",
      "light": "rgb(154, 220, 251)",
      "dark": "rgb(90, 148, 175)",
      "contrastText": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)"
    },
    "success": {
      "main": "#7cb342",
      "light": "rgb(150, 194, 103)",
      "dark": "rgb(86, 125, 46)",
      "contrastText": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)"
    },
    "common": {
      "black": "#000",
      "white": "#fff"
    },
    "grey": {
      "50": "#fafafa",
      "100": "#f5f5f5",
      "200": "#eeeeee",
      "300": "#e0e0e0",
      "400": "#bdbdbd",
      "500": "#9e9e9e",
      "600": "#757575",
      "700": "#616161",
      "800": "#424242",
      "900": "#212121",
      "A100": "#f5f5f5",
      "A200": "#eeeeee",
      "A400": "#bdbdbd",
      "A700": "#616161"
    },
    "contrastThreshold": 3,
    "tonalOffset": 0.2,
    "text": {
      "primary": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
      "secondary": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)",
      "disabled": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"
    },
    "divider": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
    "background": {
      "paper": "#fff",
      "default": "#fff"
    },
    "action": {
      "active": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)",
      "hover": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)",
      "hoverOpacity": 0.04,
      "selected": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)",
      "selectedOpacity": 0.08,
      "disabled": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)",
      "disabledBackground": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
      "disabledOpacity": 0.38,
      "focus": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
      "focusOpacity": 0.12,
      "activatedOpacity": 0.12
    }
  },
  "shape": {
    "borderRadius": 4
  },
  "mixins": {
    "toolbar": {
      "minHeight": 56,
      "@media (min-width:0px) and (orientation: landscape)": {
        "minHeight": 48
      },
      "@media (min-width:600px)": {
        "minHeight": 64
      }
    }
  },
  "shadows": [
    "none",
    "0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 3px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 7px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 2px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 5px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 9px 12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 3px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 6px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 10px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 4px 18px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 6px 7px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 11px 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 4px 20px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 7px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 12px 17px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 7px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 13px 19px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 24px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 7px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 14px 21px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 26px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 8px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 15px 22px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 28px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 8px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 16px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 30px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 8px 11px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 17px 26px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 32px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 9px 11px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 18px 28px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 7px 34px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 9px 12px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 19px 29px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 7px 36px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 20px 31px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 38px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 21px 33px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 40px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 10px 14px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 22px 35px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 42px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 11px 14px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 23px 36px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 9px 44px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
  ],
  "typography": {
    "htmlFontSize": 16,
    "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
    "fontSize": 14,
    "fontWeightLight": 300,
    "fontWeightRegular": 400,
    "fontWeightMedium": 500,
    "fontWeightBold": 700,
    "h1": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 300,
      "fontSize": "6rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.167,
      "letterSpacing": "-0.01562em"
    },
    "h2": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 300,
      "fontSize": "3.75rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.2,
      "letterSpacing": "-0.00833em"
    },
    "h3": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 400,
      "fontSize": "3rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.167,
      "letterSpacing": "0em"
    },
    "h4": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 400,
      "fontSize": "2.125rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.235,
      "letterSpacing": "0.00735em"
    },
    "h5": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 400,
      "fontSize": "1.5rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.334,
      "letterSpacing": "0em"
    },
    "h6": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 500,
      "fontSize": "1.25rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.6,
      "letterSpacing": "0.0075em"
    },
    "subtitle1": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 400,
      "fontSize": "1rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.75,
      "letterSpacing": "0.00938em"
    },
    "subtitle2": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 500,
      "fontSize": "0.875rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.57,
      "letterSpacing": "0.00714em"
    },
    "body1": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 400,
      "fontSize": "1rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.5,
      "letterSpacing": "0.00938em"
    },
    "body2": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 400,
      "fontSize": "0.875rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.43,
      "letterSpacing": "0.01071em"
    },
    "button": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 500,
      "fontSize": "0.875rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.75,
      "letterSpacing": "0.02857em",
      "textTransform": "uppercase"
    },
    "caption": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 400,
      "fontSize": "0.75rem",
      "lineHeight": 1.66,
      "letterSpacing": "0.03333em"
    },
    "overline": {
      "fontFamily": "\"Roboto\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": 400,
      "fontSize": "0.75rem",
      "lineHeight": 2.66,
      "letterSpacing": "0.08333em",
      "textTransform": "uppercase"
    }
  },
  "transitions": {
    "easing": {
      "easeInOut": "cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)",
      "easeOut": "cubic-bezier(0.0, 0, 0.2, 1)",
      "easeIn": "cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1)",
      "sharp": "cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1)"
    },
    "duration": {
      "shortest": 150,
      "shorter": 200,
      "short": 250,
      "standard": 300,
      "complex": 375,
      "enteringScreen": 225,
      "leavingScreen": 195
    }
  },
  "zIndex": {
    "mobileStepper": 1000,
    "fab": 1050,
    "speedDial": 1050,
    "appBar": 1100,
    "drawer": 1200,
    "modal": 1300,
    "snackbar": 1400,
    "tooltip": 1500
  }
}
```

But there is **no change** in the colours of my UI

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my `package.json` :

```json
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.17.10",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "webpack": "^5.72.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.16.7",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
        "@mui/material": "^5.7.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
    }
}
```

The left radio button is primary

[image]

And left radio button is secondary

[image]

The `Settings` button is 'info'

[image]

Github Repo link [here : https://github.com/YASHBRO/Sing-in-Sync/tree/development](https://github.com/YASHBRO/Sing-in-Sync/tree/development)

Comment: What kind of UI element are you trying to view when changing the coolors?

Comment: `Button` and `Radio`
I'll add the screenshots

Comment: Try installing all libraries from @mui:     "@mui/icons-material": "latest", "@mui/material": "latest", "@mui/styles": "latest", refresh your app, and maybe open in incognito see if something changes.

Comment: Those are already there, please refer to this repo for full code https://github.com/YASHBRO/Sing-in-Sync/tree/development

Comment: I am looking at the repo. Master and development branch and it looks nothing like what you pasted here. I also looked at package json and it doe not have the mui libraries installed. You did not apply the code I suggested.

Comment: Here's the link for these 3 files

App,js : https://github.com/YASHBRO/Sing-in-Sync/blob/development/frontend/src/components/App.js

Pallette,js (theme) : https://github.com/YASHBRO/Sing-in-Sync/blob/development/frontend/src/theme/Pallette.js

package.json : https://github.com/YASHBRO/Sing-in-Sync/blob/development/frontend/package.json

This package.json has `@mui/material` and `@mui/styles` but not `@mui/icons-material`, I don't it'll be needed for my purpose

Comment: The App.js does not have the <CssBaseline /> And package.json does not have the 3 libraries I suggested. Either use the "@mui" library or the"@material-ui", I suggest the first approach.

Comment: `<CssBaseline />` had not effect on it so I removed it, I'll try adding `@mui` and will let you know

Comment: This link explains how to use webpack with react and material ui, hope it helps: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-reactjs-with-webpack-4-babel-7-and-material-design-ff754586f618/

Answer (score 0):

##### Update Feb 2023

Still haven't found the solution yet and now I'm moving on.

##### My Guess

In my opinion, the MUI didn't work because I didn't use the `create-react-app` to initiate the app, instead, I did the set-up from scratch by myself.

This could be wrong, its just what I have observed

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I just ran `yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled` again and suddenly it stated working. This is my package.json. Hope it helps:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@material-table/core": "^6.2.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.7",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.13.7",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.18.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.34",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "recharts": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The theme

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#F7E224",
      light: "#FFFDE7",
      dark: "#D8C200",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#5643E0",
      light: "#FCFBFD",
      dark: "#20166C",
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

My index.ts

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import api from "./api/api";
import theme from "./theme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@emotion/react";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

api.init({
  baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 60000,
});

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <App />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score -1):

Does adding the `<CssBaseline />` help:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <CssBaseline />
      <Router />
  </ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: No, nothing changed

Comment: Try also installing "@mui/styles": "^5.7.0", Because ThemeProvider is in the styles library

Comment: Still no luck, I did install it but nothing changed

Comment: @YashJoglekar any luck with this? Also experiencing a similar issue

Comment: @Ben No, I have tried a few other methods, but none of them worked. So I decided not to waste more of my time on it and try MUI on some other project, And it did work on my other project with a similar MUI setup, I think the issue might be the initial setup of my react app, as I have NOT created it using `npx create-react-app`